# How to round the corners of the popup calendar in DatePicker?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to change the design of the DatePicker component without creating a new element since I'm working on an application in Fluent design.

I have already edited the default template of the DatePicker. I managed to change the design of the DatePicker's field and button. I was able to round the field and button corners. However, I couldn't modify the template of the popup calendar in the DatePicker. When editing the default DatePicker template, I didn't see the calendar there, although it should be present.

Is there a way to change the design of the popup calendar in DatePicker only by editing the default DatePicker template, without creating a new custom element?

[Question in Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkgUt.png)

Comment: please show how you are currently using the DatePicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `Border` with `CornerRadius` (and `Margin` on `StackPanel` and for `CalendarItem` set `Background` to White), but I am not sure if it's enough.
How it looks: [DatePicker with CornerRadius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXtj9.png)

How it's done:
Use Resources and Template from this site:
[Calendar ControlTemplate Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/calendar-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

like this: `<Window.Resources>a lot of code...<Style x:Key="CalendarItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CalendarItem}">...` and use `DatePicker` like this:

```
<DatePicker>
        <DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                            <Border
                                CornerRadius="10"
                                BorderThickness="1.5"
                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                >
                                <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Root"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            Margin="1"
                >
                                    <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem"
                    Background="White"
                    Style="{TemplateBinding CalendarItemStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
    </DatePicker>
```